# Eliminate unsed rows when making select query

Tags: database, oracle, performance, select, bigdata

I have a big database, I get about 100.000 data for a day, and database is getting bigger fastly
when I make a select query for last added rows , select query looking all datas in tables.

For example;

Select ... WHERE  INSERT_TIME > TO_TIMESTAMP('27/11/2014 16:12:09,383418' , 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS,FF')

this query look at all rows if it is added after that time or not. But I will just use last added rows so I dont wanna look at all rows if it is new or not. that is I want to eliminate all rows which I used before when searching the table for new entries.

Additionaly I dont wanna create any new table for this and dont wanna delete any rows from the table

Is there any way or solution for this?

Thank you advance!

Comment: If there is an index on `INSERT_TIME` and optimizer decides it improves performance, it's gonna be used.  If not, the engine ends up performing full table scan.

Comment: I did a quick resource about indexing and seems it can be useful for this situation, thanks for your help @a1ex07

Comment: creating an index may take significant time for a big table. You might want to specify ONLINE option

Comment: and indexing may slow down  Inserts and Updates